# Android adb backup couldn't connect issue

Tags: android, backup, adb

I am trying to create a backup of an android device using ADB.

However adb backup -all gives me this error: `adb: unable to connect for backup`
why am i getting this error?

I know that some device ask for permission to do that, it asks you whether you want to allow the pc to take a backup, but my device isn't.

I am developing android devices, i dont care about messing it up - so can you tell me how i can enable my device to ask for the permission, or even how i can fix this problem

I can use `adb shell` and it works fine, and so does `adb pull/push` however i want the backup file, so i really want adb backup to work.

Is there any other way to take an image of the entire android OS and the apps, and settings? (best is if you can point me into a direction where i can find a solution for the problem i said, but i am open to other ideas.)

Thanks!

Comment: I just discovered an Android-specific site here on Stack Exchange, and there is [a closely related question there](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23362/backup-and-restore-android-settings-and-application-through-adb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems not all versions of Android support the backup-interface.

Comment: There are solutions for this problem. Research and update you answer if you can.